# How to use .removeClass() in a userscript

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, userscripts

I'm trying to remove `hide` class from a single `div` using Violentmonkey and jQuery. My userscript is not doing anything and I cannot figure out why.

Already tried:

- adding `// @grant GM_addStyle`
- using the following selectors: `$("expand_collapse.hide")`, `$("div.expand_collapse")`, `$(".expand_collapse")`
- using Tampermonkey
- getting jQuery with `@require https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js`

This is the div:

```
<div class="expand_collapse hide">
  <a href="javascript:" id="expand_all">
        Expand
  </a>
  <a href="javascript:" id="collapse_all">
        Collapse
  </a>
</div>
```

This is my userscript:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name unhide
// @match https://example/*
// @require https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

$("div.expand_collapse.hide").removeClass("hide");
```

When I manually remove the `hide` class using Chrome inspector the Expand and Collapse links appear and work as expected. I'd like to achieve the same with the `userscript`, yet it's not working.

Comment: Make sure the script is running after the DOM has been loaded (document.ready), and are you sure that the element is not dynamically added or modified?  If it is you could try something hacky like putting your code inside a `setTimeout()` to delay its execution.

Comment: Also need to make sure that element isn't added asynchronously after dom loaded. Try adding `console.log('Length=', $("div.expand_collapse.hide").length)`

Comment: Conversely that `hide` class could also be added by other scripts after the dom is loaded

Comment: Okay, so I tried `( document ).ready(function() {
    $("div.expand_collapse.hide").removeClass("hide");
});` and it didn't help. I'm not sure how to use setTimeout .
Adding `console.log('Length=', $("div.expand_collapse.hide").length)` returns `Length= 0` so I'm guessing it is indeed added after dom is loaded. As I said, I'm a complete novice, so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the guys in the comments I figured out that the content I was trying to modify was added dynamically, therefore it wasn't yet there when my userscript was firing. Following [Archer's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57021523/how-to-use-removeclass-in-a-userscript/57021919#comment100573415_57021523) advice I added a 3-second delay with `setTimeout()` and it worked great. This is the working userscript:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name unhide
// @match https://example.com/*
// @require https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js

// ==/UserScript==

setTimeout( function() {
  $("div.expand_collapse.hide").removeClass("hide");
}, 3000 )
```

If there's an alternative/more elegant/better solution I'll be very glad to learn about it. Thanks!

EDIT: [charlietfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl) suggested to use `setInterval()` to a much shorter time (than I had to use with `setTimeout()`) and `clearInterval()` once the `div` appeared. This results in the links appearing faster. Here is the code:

```
var i = $("div.expand_collapse.hide").length;

var myInterval = setInterval(unhide, 250);

function unhide () {
  $("div.expand_collapse.hide").removeClass("hide");
}

if (i != 0) {
  clearInterval(myInterval);
};
```

Comment: You can also use a `setInterval()` also on something like `1/4` second interval time and clear the interval timer once `length` is not 0